# Angular Get Array from parent in child Component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular and am struggling with a few concepts.  I have a child component:

```html
<ng-template #days>
    <div *ngFor="let day of mappedDays">
        <job-day-listing [jobDay]="day" [canEdit]="canEdit" (vehicleSelectChange)="vehicleSelectChanged($event)" (employeeSelectChange)="employeeSelectChanged($event)" (click)="clearSelection()"></job-day-listing>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I need to access the "mappedDays" in the typescript of the child, but I can't seem to.

I tried creating an input variable in the child:

```ts
@Input() mappedDays: JobDayMapping[];
mappedDays: JobDayMapping[];
```

And in the html:

```html
<ng-template #days>
    <div *ngFor="let day of mappedDays">
        <span>[mappedDays]="mappedDays"</span>
        <job-day-listing [jobDay]="day" [canEdit]="canEdit" (vehicleSelectChange)="vehicleSelectChanged($event)" (employeeSelectChange)="employeeSelectChanged($event)" (click)="clearSelection()"></job-day-listing>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I then try to call a forEach on the array, but I receive and 'undefined' error on the mappedDays array:

```ts
this.mappedDays.forEach(md => {
  md.addEditButtonSelected = false;
});
```

Do I need a service for this?

Comment: The code formatting is really making this a tough call, but in your second bigger code snippet [mappedDays]="mappedDays" is not part of the job-day-listing tag but instead is inside a span tag? and as such, the input of the component stays null. This should either give you a compile error in the template (HTML file) or I guess you re just seeing the text [mappedDays]="mappedDays"  in you website ;)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to format the code.  I copied it in and in my screen it looks correct, but in the display, it doesn't. I tried adding extra returns, spacing, etc.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is fine (passing `mappedDays` into the child via an `@Input()` binding), but there are some errors in your code:

---

Your current code

```
<ng-template #days>
  <div *ngFor="let day of mappedDays">
    <span>[mappedDays]="mappedDays"</span>
    <job-day-listing
      [jobDay]="day"
      [canEdit]="canEdit"
      (vehicleSelectChange)="vehicleSelectChanged($event)"
      (employeeSelectChange)="employeeSelectChanged($event)"
      (click)="clearSelection()">
    </job-day-listing>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

- Not sure why you need the `<span>` tag
- The `[mappedDays]` attribute is on the wrong side of the span's opening tag (`>`), so it will just be listed as text within the span. Instead you want to place this inside the opening tag of your child component

---

The following should work:

```
<ng-template #days>
  <div *ngFor="let day of mappedDays">
    <job-day-listing
      [mappedDays]="mappedDays"
      [jobDay]="day"
      [canEdit]="canEdit"
      (vehicleSelectChange)="vehicleSelectChanged($event)"
      (employeeSelectChange)="employeeSelectChanged($event)"
      (click)="clearSelection()">
    </job-day-listing>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
export class JobDayListingComponent {
  @Input() mappedDays;

  someFn() {
    this.mappedDays.forEach(md => { md.addEditButtonSelected = false; });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :) Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you believe it to be so!